# How to access Google Chrome ARC app filesystem in Chrome as of 2016?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I created this account to ask this question (and possibly more in the future), as I have constantly searched to no avail. In the latest version of Chrome 64-bit (May 2016) there is no option in DevTools -> Options -> Experiments called 'FileSystem Inspection'. Is there another way to access the filesystem of a chrome app/extension or is it locked down now?

Thanks,
Jonathon

Answer (score 0):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/arc/arc/+/master/src/build/metadata/definitions.json

Use either {"enableAdb": "true"} and access via adb, or {"enableExternalDirectory": "true"} and select a local directory.